# Google Analytics: how to split traffic from Google search into different Google sites (google.com, google.fr, ...)?

Tags: google-analytics, split-testing

As 75% of my traffic are generated by Google search, I am asking myself if there is a way to split this traffic into the different local Google domains as `google.com`, `google.fr`, `google.be` and so one in the Google Analytics?

When I try to digg into the Google Analytics reports, I land always at source: "google" without more detail.

Any idea if it is possible to do it? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved relatively simply with Google Analytics' default state.

Set your time period, then navigate to:-

Standard Reports > Traffic Sources > Sources > Referrals

Then click on the 'advanced' link to create an advanced filter (below).

[image: google analytics advanced filter]

Then include 'google' in the source containing like the below then hit apply.

[image: filter sources by google in analytics]

Then what you should see is all referring sites where the domain contains 'google' - like the screenshot below.

[image: referrals by google search engines]

Hope that helps! :)

## Edit

Just found a useful guide on this at [Econsultancy](http://econsultancy.com/uk/blog/7822-how-to-view-regional-search-traffic-in-google-analytics) with additional configuration on this if of use.

## Edit 2

Following on from my answer comments, you can also use [_addOrganic()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addOrganic) in your GA tracking code to add additional search engines to be included as a potential search engine traffic source.

For example:-

```
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.co.uk', 'q', true]);
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.fr', 'q', true]);
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.ru', 'q', true]);
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.com.hk', 'q', true]);
```

And in context:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
            _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.co.uk', 'q', true]);
            _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.fr', 'q', true]);
            _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.ru', 'q', true]);
            _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.com.hk', 'q', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    //]]>
</script>
```

More on this method [here](http://gatipoftheday.com/break-out-google-co-uk-google-in-and-google-ru-as-separate-organic-sources/).

Comment: in fact, my problem is that in "referrals" there are e.g. 5O visits for google local sites (following the procedure you suggest) but still, in the "search", I have more than 1000 visits as "google" and there (in the "search" section of GA) this method doesn't work. And of course, I am interested of splitting this main visitors source (the 1000 visits coming from "google"). Any idea?

Comment: In that case you can create additional organic matches in the tracking code. For example: `_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'google.co.uk', 'q', true]);`. I will update my answer with this shortly.